# Installed Android Studio and getting error: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found

Tags: android-studio

> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

I downloaded Android Studio and this error is coming whenever I try to make a new project. Before this when I downloaded Android Studio, I tried to import a project from Github and still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have updated your android studio version to Flamingo (2022.2.1) 
AGP 8.0.0 does not work on previous versions of Android Studio.